# Installing the correct version of GDAL

Tags: django, python-3.x, geolocation

My version of Python is [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 but I cannot see a release 1916 in -

1. http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php
2. https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal
3. https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Possibly I am misreading the websites. To be honest I found https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ very confusing to navigate.

Can anyone give me any guidance?

**Update**

I used the ​64bit OSGeo4W network installer from https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
and everything is working now.

To find out if you need the 32 or 64 bit installer you can do

```
(project2_env) C:\Users\HP\django_project3>python
```

And it will give you below information.

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/

Comment: I will look at the link now.